# Is it correct to use service like this in Symfony 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony

So is this allowed to use or is it better to inject the service in the controller's constructor? I know there is a better way, but for the sake of laziness can I do that?

```
class someController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test")
     */
    public function someFunction() 
    {
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine();
        $service = new someService($manager);

        $all =  $service->getAll();
        dump($all);exit;
    }
}


------------------------------------------------
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class someService implements someServiceInterface 
{
   /**
    * @var ManagerRegistry
    */
    private $manager;

    public function __construct($manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function getAll() 
    {
        return $this->manager->getRepository(SomeEntity::class)->findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to inject it. It's not exactly difficult, right? You've probably put more effort into creating this question than to just have done it :)

Comment: You can, but it goes against the SOLID principles.

Comment: Short answer: no. Your service is not really a service on Symfony point of view considering it's not injected directly via the constructor of your controller (or the action method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have issues with your service because you need to inject the entity manager inside. Please notice there's nothing wrong with that. Here is a code that should work:

Let's say we inject the service:

```
// Better use camel case with upper first letter
class SomeController extends Controller 
{    
    /**
     * @Route("/test")
     */
    public function someFunction(SomeService $someService) 
    {
        $all =  $someService->getAll();
        dump($all);exit;
    }
}
```

You could inject directly in the constructor of your Controller but here I use action injection, [see documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller.html#controller-accessing-services).

Here is how look your service:

```
class SomeService implements SomeServiceInterface 
{
   /**
    * @var EntityManagerInterface
    */
    private $manager;

    // Type hinting matters here!
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function getAll() 
    {
        return $this->manager->getRepository(SomeEntity::class)->findAll();
    }
}
```

This works out of the box in Symfony 4.x setups because they define service autoloading and autowire by default. Which are features available in Symfony 3.4, [see documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html).

But in order to configure all of this manually, you may need this configuration:

```
You\SomeController:
    autowire: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
You\SomeService:
    autowire: true
```

Finally, if you are looking for a way to make lazy services, it's a feature of the dependency injection component of Symfony. See, again, [documentation over here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/lazy_services.html).

Answer (score 1):

While not incorrect (your app won't crash) it is not recommended. 
I suggest your read this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

As you already guess you can inject your service in your constructor.
Simply enable it in your config.yml by adding

```
App\Controller\:
    resource: '../../Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

It will solve you a lot of trouble and refactoring when your service will need an other dependence

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your service directly into a controller using

```
public function someFunction(someService $service) //I do that because I'm lazier than you.
{
    //your code
}
```

auto-wiring will search for your service and inject it.

In services.yaml, you can set :

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
```

More informations concerning auto wiring can be found in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeController extends AbstractController // Controller deprecated since 4.0
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test")
     */
    public function someFunction(SomeServiceInterface $someService) // that's all what you need, "autowire: true" by default since 3.4
    {
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine();
        $all =  $someService->getAll();
        dump($all);exit;
    }
}


------------------------------------------------
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class SomeService implements SomeServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ManagerRegistry
     */
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $manager) // autowire
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->manager->getRepository(SomeEntity::class)->findAll();
    }
}
```